# Show that two subspaces of test functions are equal

Tags: real-analysis

I need to show that subspace $D_{01} = \{\phi(x) \in D: \exists \int_\mathbb{R} \frac{\phi(x)}{x}dx \}$ is equal to $\{\phi(x) \in D: \phi(0) = 0\}$

I have no idea how to show this.

As usual, I wanted to show that one is a subset of another, and it is intuitively clear that the second must be a subset of the first, I thought about Taylor series and that it must start from the first degree, but, obviously, function is not necessarily analytical. What about another inclusion, i don't know what to do at all.

Thank you for help.

Comment: In general, how do you show that two spaces are equal? Can you show $\subseteq$ and then $\supseteq$? That's where to start. If you cannot do that, explain why you are having difficulties, and I'm sure someone will be able to help more.

Comment: As usual, I wanted to show that one is a subset of another, and it is intuitively clear that the second must be a subset of the first, I thought about Taylor series, but function is not necessarily analytical. What about another inclusion, i don't know what to do at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By definition, $\frac{\phi(x)}{x}$ is integrable iff $\left\lvert \frac{\phi(x)}{x}\right\rvert$ is integrable. We let $\phi\in D$ such that $\phi(0) = c\neq 0$. Then, as $\phi$ is smooth, there must be some $\delta > 0$ such that $\lvert \phi(x)-c\rvert\leq \frac{c}{2}$ for all $\lvert x\rvert\leq \delta$. This would imply $$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \left\lvert \frac{\phi(x)}{x}\right\rvert\,\mathrm{d}x\geq \int_0^{\delta} \frac{c}{2x}\,\mathrm{d}x$$ which is unbounded, so $\phi\notin D_{01}$. This implies that if $\phi\in D_{01}$, then $\phi(0) = 0$. Now we will show that $\phi\in D$ and $\phi(0) = 0$ implies $\phi\in D_{01}$. First, note that $$\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{\phi(x)}{x} = \lim_{x\to 0} \frac{\phi(x)-\phi(0)}{x} = \phi'(0)$$ so for any $\epsilon > 0$ there must be some $\delta > 0$ such that $\left\lvert \frac{\phi(x)}{x}-\phi'(0)\right\rvert\leq \epsilon$ for all $\lvert x\rvert\leq \delta$. We let $\phi$ be supported on compact $K$ and bounded by $M\geq 0$. Then, $$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \left\lvert \frac{\phi(x)}{x}\right\rvert\,\mathrm{d}x = \left(\int_{-\delta}^{\delta}+\int_{K\setminus (-\delta, \delta)}\right) \left\lvert \frac{\phi(x)}{x}\right\rvert\,\mathrm{d}x\leq 2\delta(\lvert \phi'(0)\rvert+\epsilon)+\frac{M}{\delta}\cdot m(K\setminus (-\delta, \delta))$$ where $m(S)$ is the Lebesgue measure of $S$. This implies that $\frac{\phi(x)}{x}$ is integrable, so $\phi\in D_{01}$.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Unfortunately can't upvote your answer, it's clear and simple!